# How could I handle a Window's Message?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm working on some `CreateWindow` things.
My work need I to insert a Button into one of an Application's Window, and when I click the button, my application can do something. That Application isn't my Application, so I think I need to do some "hook thing".
And I tried this:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowEx("className",NULL)
CreateWindowEx(...hwnd...)
```

Its worked. The Button successfully inserted into target application.

but when I try to handle that window's message
I failed.
This `hwnd` is belongs to my application `hInstance`, but my Application has its own message loop by CEF.
I tried `SetWindowsHookEx`,but its not working.
Whatever I do, it will not handled.
and if i use `while(GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))`,it will block my application's thread

`WNDCLASS xxx` and `RegisterClass(xxx)`
or `CreateWindow(className)`
 confused me.

I try to use `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` but the `while()` will block my application's thread
and in my application's `wndProc`, there is no `WM_COMMAND` message in.

```cpp
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, 0, L"TCustomBaseForm" , NULL);
    HWND hwndButton = CreateWindowEx(0L,_T("Button"), L"Btn",  WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE| BS_PUSHBUTTON, 435, 45, 35, 45, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    DWORD dwProcId = 0;
    DWORD dwThreadId = 0;
    dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndButton, &dwProcId);
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, Hookproc, g_hInstance, dwProcId);
```

Until now, my "inserted button" never work.
So, is there any way to make this "inserted window" or button same as a MFC button that, when I click it, I can handle a message like `WM_LBUTTONCLICK` in my `WndProc`?

Comment: Learn about [windows hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). In essence you build a DLL and register a function in that DLL as windows hook, and then all processes will load that DLL and call the hook. The hook for you is I believe `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

Comment: @Dialecticus depending on the type of hooking needed, `SetWinEventHook()` may be better to use than `SetWindowsHookEx()`. No DLL needed, can target specific HWNDs target than globally, and it can hook standard actions like button clicks.

Comment: Creating a child window whose parent is in another process, especially one that doesn't know about or coordinate with your process, is a very bad idea. See: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Answer (score 0):

A button sends a `WM_COMMAND` message to its parent window when you click it.

There are at least two ways to deal with this without hooking:

- Create the button as a child of a `STATIC` control (or a custom window) that you also create. You need to [subclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) the `STATIC` control to receive the message.
- Subclass the button and catch the mouse up message and space/enter key-down messages.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all. I did it.
I create a Window that have a button. And I use `SetParent(myWindowHwnd,myTargetWindowHwnd)` and handle the button's click event in my window, it works.
No hook, no problems.
Thank you all very much.
And thanks for edit my question, for my poooooooooooor English.
I've learned a lot about Windows Hook.

Comment: Please re-read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552824/how-could-i-handle-a-windows-message#comment101581532_57552824).

Comment: Thank you. I read that twice. I can image what will happen. But my this ```Window``` just like a "shortcut button" which just have one action, it won't be complicated. And my project is close to deadline, so I have noway. I'm new at C++ and only I can do this in my company. I will learn these well in the future.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether *your* message loop is simple. You have attached it to another one, which you don't control and presumably *is* complex. See how easy you can deadlock: [A pathological program which ignores the keyboard, and understanding the resulting behavior based on what we know about the synchronous input](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130606-00/?p=4153). Regardless, SO is about quality answers. Any given deadline doesn't right a wrong.

Comment: ```Any given deadline doesn't right a wrong```      I will REMEMBER THAT.